# Navigator InjectionToken in tests causes ReferenceError: Navigator is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have following abstraction of Navigator

```
export const NAVIGATOR: InjectionToken<Navigator> = new InjectionToken<Navigator>(
  'An abstraction over window.navigator object',
  {
    factory: () => inject(WINDOW).navigator,
  },
);
```

As well as following abstraction of Window

```
import { inject, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

export const WINDOW: InjectionToken<Window> = new InjectionToken<Window>(
  'An abstraction over global window object',
  {
    factory: () => {
      const { defaultView }: any = inject(DOCUMENT);

      if (!defaultView) {
        throw new Error('Window is not available');
      }

      return defaultView;
    },
  },
);
```

I need this in order to be able to mock providers to be able to tests classes.
But unfortunately every time I inject Navigator Token into the service

```
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(NAVIGATOR) private navigator: Navigator,
  ) {}
}
```

And I run unit tests I see following error:

```
ReferenceError: Navigator is not defined

      3 |   constructor(
    > 4 |     @Inject(NAVIGATOR) private navigator: Navigator,
        |                                           ^
      6 |   ) {}
```

tsconfig.ts is as follow

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "assets",
    "translations"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.spec.ts looks as follows

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: What does WINDOW look like? You probably want the build in DOCUMENT token - on which you can use defaultView as window.

Comment: Updated. Now you can see how window InjectionToken looks like. But keep in mind that Window token doesn't cause any issues when I inject it as a dependancy

Comment: What version of Angular and Typescript are you using and how do you execute the jest tests?

Comment: Angular 12, Typescript 4.2 are used. Jest is used to run tests

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mock your service as follows:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NAVIGATOR,
            useFactory: () => ({
                myMethodToMock: () => {},
            }),
        },
    ],
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it makes no difference mate. My assumption is that the problem llies in tsconfig. Because Navigator is a part of dom library, which is not present in node.js

Comment: Hmm, and in your `tsconfig.spec.ts`, do you have `"types": ["jasmine", "node", "dom"]`?

Comment: you can see the content of both tsconfig and tsconfig.spec in my post @Wandrille